# installation of ubuntu off line and alongside windows XP

Tags: installation, 13.04, autorun

Can 'Ubuntu' be installed off line and continue to also operate off line? after downloading Ubuntu or before downloading it, how can i make it to be on auto run format for easy set up command?

Comment: what do you mean by "operate offline?" you mean run from bootable cd or usb?

Comment: have you gone through http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be installed with out internet as well as run with out it.  However if u wanted updates on install u would need internet.